# Using a different thumbnail from youtube embeded video code?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

Is it possible to use a different thumbnail from a youtube video while using the youtube embed code? Note this is from a youtube video that I did not upload and do not have login access to in order to change the thumbnails inside youtube.

I know it's possible to get different thumbnails from videos, as can be seen here: http://vidthumb.com/process.php?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3Di_BhgfESO0Y

But can you choose a different one than the one the user chose, or was automatically chosen? Again, I don't have login access to the file so I am wondering if one can use a code to get it from the embed code.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

According to the Google Documentation, In order to change the thumbnail of a video on YouTube, the option to ***edit*** must appear on the channel. Since you can edit something only if you are able to *login* hence the thumbnail cannot be changed by someone who do not have an account access.

I think the URL you posted for the website works on a program that captures the screenshot of the video at different point in time during the entire duration of the video. There are various ways to do that, here is one [example](http://www.codejava.net/java-se/graphics/how-to-capture-screenshot-programmatically-in-java).

Google has not disclosed any API that would fetch the thumbnails from a youtube channel that you are not logged into.